# emacs lisp: how to append to the list "LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes"?

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp

I would like to append some regex to the latex command `LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes`. I tried

```
(setq LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes
        (append LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes (list "\\.foo" "\\.bar")))
```

but I receive the following warning:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/myusername/.emacs':

Symbol's value as variable is void: LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

How can I append some strings/suffixes to this list?

Comment: Thanks for helping, I added the warning above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to modify the value of the variable before the package defining it is loaded. `C-h v` shows that that variable is defined in the "latex.el" file, so try doing the following instead:

```
(eval-after-load 'latex
  '(setq LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes
     (append LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes (list "\\.foo" "\\.bar"))))
```

Note that `eval-after-load` is a function, and requires the code you want evaluated to be quoted -- a bit confusing as it's different from the similarly-named `eval-when-compile` and friends, which are macros.

BTW, you can also use `add-to-list` to add items to a list, with a third argument of `t` to make it append rather than cons them onto the front. `add-to-list` is also a function, so here the name of the variable needs to be quoted. Sometimes this is more readable than the combination of `setq` and `append`, but you can only add one item at a time:

```
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-clean-intermediate-suffixes "\\.foo" t)
```

The other advantage of this is that it will check whether `"\\.foo"` is already present in the list before adding it -- useful for things like load paths.